# Cross-domain font problems

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, fonts

*Sorry for the long post, but you need some background info before my question since this is a strange setup and it's quite complex.*

I have two fonts that's needs to be in a newletter.

First font, `Cyclone`, is in a format `OTF`.

The second, `Albert`, is format `EOT` and `WOFF`.

We have a system that send the newsletters for us, i only need to upload a html file to that system, that contains the structure, images and newsletter content, and upload images that needs to be in the newsletter.

After that i can preview it by sending it to my self.

1. First, i can't upload fonts or anything else to the newsletter
   system besides images and html.
2. Second, i have uploaded both fonts, and the css to our webiste's media
   folder(public folder) where we also load images to the website.
3. Third, i or anyone else, have no access to the `.htaccess` file, and we
   will never get it, since the site is hosted somewhere, and to get
   that fixed for cross-domain for newsletters is to big of a task for
   such a small job.

In the newsletter i am loading the font like this:

```
@import url(xxx.com/media/fonts/albert.css);
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Albert;
src: url("fsalbertwebregular.woff") format("woff");
}
```

have also tried this setup in the css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Albert';
src: url('FSAlbertWeb-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 */
src: url('FSAlbertWeb-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('FSAlbertWeb-Regular.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And then use the font on the body:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Albert', times new roman;
}
```

But doing this, i am getting this error/warning:

```
CORS-headeren 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

The funny thing is, when i used the `Cyclone.otf` font, it worked fine.
When i use the `albert.eot` or `albert.woff`, it's not working.
I then tried to convert the `woff` to `otf`, and use that, didn't work - same error/warning.

The setup might sounds strange, and is sure is, i have tried to draw how the setup is, so hope it makes a bit more sense.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this, what needs to be done without editing the `.htaccess` file. And why does `Cyclone.otf` work and not the others, even after converting them to `otf`?

Comment: I dont think fancy fonts work on email unless you use images. You can only use fonts that are on the users machine. It works on a website because the user caches and downloads the font as part of the web page. Emails dont work that way.

Comment: I got Cyclone to work, so something is working?

Comment: Is that font on your machine? did it work on a machine that does not have that font installed? - If it worked for one then it should work for all.

Comment: Also you need to test it with an email system like email on acid to see how it looks in different email systems. such as gmail, yahoo mail, outlook and so on

Comment: Whats your setup that works with Cyclone? How does it  differ from this? Or not at all?

Comment: Read this: http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/

Comment: The Cyclone font is the same setup as the first example of the CSS, except its otf instead. and that worked perfect. I have the font on my machine since i needed to upload it, but it's not installed, and is not in the windows font folder.

Comment: UPDATE: I just checked to be sure, and yes the Cyclone font was installed. Checked with a college just now, and it didn't work for him, we then installed the font, and it then worked.

Comment: @PatrickR Thats how fonts work in email. If its a small bit of text you can use an image. but really should just use one of the base fonts. The fancy fonts might work on apple devices but thats about it.

Comment: *theoretically* you could use an `iframe` in your email code. **practically**, almost every email provider does **not** allow it. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/   ...just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special fonts wont work in emails. You have to still use the basic web fonts like arial.

If it worked for you on one machine it may mean that you have that font installed. Try testing it on another machine and see what results you get. Also it can be worth testing your email code through a system like email on acid to see how it reacts and breaks to different email systems such as gmail or outlook.

Here is a guide to email fonts: http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/